# null termination didn't appear in the array on strcpy-ing

Tags: c++, c-strings

While I was using `c_str()` to transform `std::string` into *C-style* string, I didn't see the last character overridden by the null-termination which `c_str()` is supposed to add in this program:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include<cstring>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string s = "helloworld";
    char c[10];
    strcpy(c, s.c_str());
    cout << c << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

What I am asking is why `d` is being printed (added to `c`) as I was expecting *null-termination* to be there. What am I missing here?

Comment: `strcpy` puts the terminator *after* the the string it writes. If the buffer is too small, that's your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has undefined behavior, because `c`, the array into which you copy the string, does not allocate enough space for null terminator.

The number of characters that you copy is 10, so you need an array of 11 to accommodate the null terminator.

To avoid overrun troubles like that with statically allocated arrays, use dynamic allocation instead:

```
char *c = new char[s.size()+1];
strcpy(c, s.c_str());
cout << c <<endl;
delete[] c;
```

Answer (score 1):

You have undefined behaviour, `"helloworld"` is actually `"helloworld\0"`, that is 11 characters. `strcpy` tries to copy over the whole string including NUL but `c` is only able to hold 10 characters.

Answer (score 0):

`strcpy` does not know how long the target array is. It copies until (and including) the terminating 0 byte. So, the whole string `helloworld\0` is copied. Note that this is 11 chars and you might as well get a crash.